# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence (Assigning a list to a new created column)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, arraylist, nlp

I have this code, which basically reads a csv file, founds similar words found in one of the columns of the csv file (which is a string text) and a dictionary of keywords I created, and then returns the words as a list.

```
import pandas as pd
import re
from nltk.tokenize.treebank import TreebankWordDetokenizer
from langdetect import detect
from sentiment_analysis_spanish import sentiment_analysis
from textblob import TextBlob
import unidecode

df1=pd.read_csv('TFG1.csv', encoding = 'utf8')

def find_all_words(words, sentence):
    all_words = re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)
    words_found = []
    for word in words:

        if word in all_words:
            words_found.append(word)
    return "Words found:", words_found.__len__(), " The words are:", words_found


english_dic=['sage', 'selection']
spanish_dic=['grupo', 'bien']

df1["Reescribe aquí / Rewrite here"].apply(unidecode.unidecode) #para quitar acentos
TreebankWordDetokenizer().detokenize(df1["Reescribe aquí / Rewrite here"])

i=1
f=0

df1["Words count"]=0
df1["Words found"] = None

for rows in [x.lower() for x in df1["Reescribe aquí / Rewrite here"]]:

    if detect(rows)=='en':
        df1["Words count"].iloc[f]=find_all_words(english_dic, rows)[1]
        df1["Words found"].iloc[f]=find_all_words(english_dic, rows)[3]
        print(i, "-", rows, find_all_words(english_dic, rows))

    elif detect(rows)=='es':
        df1["Words count"].iloc[f]=find_all_words(spanish_dic, rows)[1]
        df1["Words found"].iloc[f]=find_all_words(spanish_dic, rows)[3]
        print(i, "-", rows, find_all_words(spanish_dic, rows))

    f+=1
    i+=1
```

The function find_all_words() returns 2 things; the number of words found, for example, if the dictionary I have `english_dic=['sage', 'selection']` and the text is; **sage said that the selection is good** it will return:
**Words found: 2
The words are: [sage, selection]**

However, it gives me an error when I try to assign the list to a new column.

```
        df1["Words found"].iloc[f]=find_all_words(english_dic, rows)[3]
```

It returns this error: **ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence**

Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: I ran the program on Jupyter Notebook and it worked perfectly, however it doesn't work on PyCharm. How can this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `'Words found'` column type to object before trying to initialize it:

```py
...

df1['Words found'] = df1['Words found'].astype(object)
df1['Words found'] = None
```

Edit: if this is the first time referencing `'Words found'` first create the column:

```py
df1['Words found'] = None
df1['Words found'] = df1['Words found'].astype(object)
```

Comment: **Still getting an error:** Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/carlos/PycharmProjects/TFG/Re.py", line 49, in <module>
    df1["Words found"] = df1["Words found"].astype(object)
  File "/Users/carlos/TFG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2906, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "/Users/carlos/TFG/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2900, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Words found'

Comment: Hey @Carlos, you could try switching up the initialization and the type setting: first set to `None`, then try setting the column type with `.astype(object)`

Comment: Still have the same error. However, if I run it on Jupyter Notebook, it works perfectly fine. do you know why this could be?

Comment: Are you using the same python version inside Jupyter?

Comment: Yes, in both I'm using Python 3

Comment: In Jupyter, after running a cell, the variables are updated. You don't get a KeyError, because you probably added the key to the dateframe before you reference it.

Comment: Also, you could try something like `pd.show_versions()` to list the exact pandas/python versions that you are using.